# Understanding memory management in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, dealloc

I am in the process of learnig objective-c and programming an iPad app. One thing I keep tripping myself up on and having to re-read is memory management. I am getting there...slowly. Basic rules such as for every `alloc` / `retain` you must have a `release` is useful. However, one relatively basic thing eludes me and I wonder if someone could explain...

Take the following code...

```
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
myArray = [someNSSet allObjects];
```

This is relatively straight forward coding and would require a `[myArray release]` statement.

However, I keep seeing examples of (and indeed, I have used extensively the following 'short cut'...

```
NSArray *myArray = (NSArray *)[someNSSet allObjects];
```

How, as far as I understand when you use the `(NSString *)` you dont need to use a `[myArray release]` statement, but I dont understand why.

Could someone possible explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first line:

```
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] init]
```

some amount of memory is allocated for an array (actually in this case it is senseless since the size of the array is 0. Keep in mind that NSArray is immutable!). 
The variable myArray holds the address of the first byte of the reserved memory area.

Now in the second line you change the value of myArray which now will point to the first byte of the memory area where [someNSSet allObjects] is stored. At this moment you do not know any more where the array is stored what you've created in the first line. And so you have a leak.

The line:

```
NSArray *myArray = (NSArray *)[someNSSet allObjects];
```

is correct, since you do not reserve any memory at this point. If you are not using ARC you might call retain in order to keep GC away from the referenced block of memory. In other way you might receive a BAD_EXEC when the owner of the object releases it and you try to access it through e.g.: [myArray objectAtIndex:0]

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
myArray = [someNSSet allObjects];
```

this code is leaking `myArray` because you lose the reference to `NSArray` that you've allocated on the first line; you don't need to `alloc` here, because on the second line you're assigning a new value to `myArray`.

```
NSArray *myArray = (NSArray *)[someNSSet allObjects];
```

and this code example is perfectly fine, you're assigning the result of `[someNSSet allObjects]` to `myArray` pointer and you don't own the returned value, so you don't need to care about releasing it.

Consider using ARC (Automatic Retain Counting) for you project. With ARC the compiler takes care of retain counts so you don't have to, in fact aren't allowed to. There is a refactoring that will convert a current project.

Comment: Why dont I 'own the returned value'. Who/what does?

Comment: @BenThompson: When you create an object(new or alloc, copy or mutableCopy), it has a retain count of 1 and you own it.
When you send an object a retain message, its retain count is incremented by 1 and you own it too. You only need to release objects that you own.

Comment: @Ben: It's most likely that the autorelease pool is the owner of the object returned from `allObjects`. The other possibility is the set object, but this would really only happen if the set was just exposing an object it already owned, rather than creating a new array. Except for an understanding of what's going on in the background, however, you shouldn't concern yourself with who owns things. Either you do or you don't, and that's all you need to consider.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, there is a leak in the first code you posted. so you must add a release:

```
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
[myArray release];
myArray = [someNSSet allObjects];
```

In fact, when you obtain an object through a method that starts with `alloc`, `new` or `copy`, you own it, and you should release it. That's why, here you should release the array you obtained using the method `alloc`. This convention makes it easy to know when you own objects and when you don't. So remember: `alloc`, `new` or `copy`.

As for the second example, you obtained the array though a method that doesn't start with one of the three words (`alloc`, `new` or `copy`), so you don't own the object, and you are not responsible of releasing it. In fact, the array you obtained is an autoreleased object, which means that even though its retain count is currently 1, it will be automatically released when something called the autorelease pool is drained.

Here is a reference about [Memory Management Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1).

Comment: may be better invert line 2 with line 3 in your answer code (or use autorelease instead of release)

Comment: The `release` in line 2 is to balance the `alloc` in line 2, so that the old value of `myArray` doesn't leak. We need to do that before assigning a new value to `myArray`.

Comment: yes, of course, but if you release it, at line 3 myArray doesn't exist anymore, it's not more allocated and could give you error, and you couldn't use it. you must balance alloc with release, and use your objects between these 2 lines. or not?

Comment: No, I assign a new value to `myArray`, so its old value is not relevant. What line 3 does is make `myArray` point to the same address as the array returned by `[someNSSet allObjects];` Thats the equivalent of `NSArray *myArray = nil; myArray = [someNSSet allObjects];`